# Cannot access Flask Rest api with docker anywhere on internet via VPS

Tags: python, docker, flask, vps

I have a basic REST API implemented in Flask. I implemented Docker to containerize it and it works well locally. I then was able to push my project on a VPS cause I want my Flask api to be access anywhere on the internet.
But I wasn't able to do so, I can't access my Flask api on the host server. I'm completely new to Docker and VPS, but based on what I was able to figure out on various forums, this is what I have set up.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR     /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN python3 -m pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
aiohttp==3.8.6
aiohttp-retry==2.8.3
aiosignal==1.3.1
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrs==23.1.0
blinker==1.6.3
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.3.1
click==8.1.7
distlib==0.3.7
filelock==3.12.4
Flask==2.3.0
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
flask-marshmallow==0.14.0
Flask-MySQL==1.5.2
Flask-MySQLdb==2.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
frozenlist==1.4.0
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.29.0
multidict==6.0.4
mysqlclient==2.2.0
packaging==23.2
platformdirs==3.11.0
PyJWT==2.8.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.22
twilio==8.10.0
typing_extensions==4.8.0
urllib3==2.0.7
virtualenv==20.24.5
Werkzeug==3.0.0
yarl==1.9.2
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_cors import CORS
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sqlalchemy import text
from urllib.parse import quote

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000"])


db = SQLAlchemy()
db = SQLAlchemy(engine_options={"pool_size": 10, 'pool_recycle': 280, "poolclass":QueuePool, "pool_pre_ping":True})

mysql =MySQL()

@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def as_dict(self):
        excluded_fields = ['id']
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c if field.name not in excluded_fields}

@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def as_dict(self):
        excluded_fields = ['id']
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c if field.name not in excluded_fields}



app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:pwd@127.0.0.1/test'

db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_user():
    users = User.query.all()
    return jsonify(users)

@app.route('/user/<firstname>', methods=['GET'])
def user_byfirstname(firstname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(firstname = firstname).first()
    return jsonify(user.as_dict())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

I then went on the VPS Terminal, and ran `$ docker build -t myapp:latest`.

The build is successful, and I can see my app listed in the Docker VPS app

I then ran

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:5000 myapp:latest
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py:144: SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as __main__.User, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.
  super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 581-248-767
```

Docker VPS shows myapp is in use.

So far, so good. But this is where I start running into issues.

I run the cmd to know my vps host IP :

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'  ad37e8ffe744 //container Id
```

it returned `172.17.0.2`

I then used Postman on my local machine to test it:

```
 172.17.0.2:8080/users
```

Postman throws the error : `Error: Request timed out`

I really don't know what to do or where to go from here, every source I've tried has given me a slight variation on what I have already attempted, and I'm no closer to getting this to work. Please help, how can I access my docker server anywhere accross the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is wrong (not familiar with the VPS solution you are using) but i think the IP `172.17.0.2` is from the docker engine, not the public IP that you can reach from your local machine. Since the docker container runs correctly in your local, i think you need to look into your VPS connectivity config. My 2 cents.

Comment: I use Hostinger VPS.

Comment: 172.17.0.2 is definitely an internal docker IP and part of the RFC 1918 private address space and will never work over the internet.  Use the public IP from your VPS instead

Comment: I found my public ip address, and it still doesn't work. So there is no way that the problem could come from Docker?

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is pretty much useless, and there's no reason to look it up.  You should be able to use the host's (VPS instance's) IP address or DNS name, and the first `-p` port number 8080.  The second `-p` port number 5000 needs to match what the process in the container is using, and that looks right.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your flask app is being bound to 127.0.0.1:5000 on the container side even though your app says 0.0.0.0 perhaps docker is binding the host to 127.0.0.1 as well.
You can try explicitly binding your bind app to 0.0.0.0 on the host side like this:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 0.0.0.0:8080:5000 myapp:latest
```

You can also show your list of port mappings by using the docker port command as documented at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/